# Inverse map and use if inside a map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In the categories.map((category) => () I need to inverse the elements of the categories.map and check for category.isFeatured befor making a link but it doesn't let me make an if statement.

```
const Header = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    getCategories().then((newCategories) => setCategories(newCategories))
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto mb-8 px-10">
      <div className="inline-block w-full border-b border-blue-400 py-8">
        <div className="block md:float-left">
          <span className="cursor-pointer text-4xl font-bold text-white">
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="hidden md:float-left md:contents">
          {categories.map((category) => (
            <Link key={category.slug} href={`/category/${category.slug}`}>
              <span className="mt-2 ml-4 cursor-pointer align-middle font-semibold text-white md:float-right">
                {category.name}
                {console.log(category.name)}
              </span>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: what does "inverse the elements" entail? reverse order? that's where array.reverse can help - filtering can be done using array.filter

Comment: What do you need to do after checking for `category.isFeatured` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bravo is right on the Array.reverse in the comments.

You also need to add {} in the .map, check category.isFeatured, and remove any nulls (or you'll get blank rows).

For example the following will reverse the order, return the link if category.isFeatured, else return null. Finally it will remove all nulls with filter(Boolean) - a nifty trick:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Header = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getCategories().then((newCategories) => setCategories(newCategories));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto mb-8 px-10">
      <div className="inline-block w-full border-b border-blue-400 py-8">
        <div className="block md:float-left">
          <span className="cursor-pointer text-4xl font-bold text-white">
            <Link href={"/"}>CRBStuffReviews</Link>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="hidden md:float-left md:contents">
          {categories
            .reverse()
            .map((category) => {
              return category.isFeatured ? (
                <Link key={category.slug} href={`/category/${category.slug}`}>
                  <span className="mt-2 ml-4 cursor-pointer align-middle font-semibold text-white md:float-right">
                    {category.name}
                    {console.log(category.name)}
                  </span>
                </Link>
              ) : null;
            })
            .filter(Boolean)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It worked! curiously enough while the array is inversed it still appears the same way on page.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<div className="hidden md:float-left md:contents">
        {mrGlobalRequest?.map((category) => {
          if (category.isFeatured) 
           
         
          return (
            <div key={category.slug} href={`/category/${category.slug}`}>
              <span className="mt-2 ml-4 cursor-pointer align-middle font-semibold text-white md:float-right">
                {category.name}
                {console.log(category.name)}
              </span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the map callback function, you need to use curly bracket

> {}

Inside the curly bracket you can use the IF statement

So, Your code will looks like this

```
    const Header = () => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
      useEffect(() => {
        getCategories().then((newCategories) => setCategories(newCategories))
      }, [])
      return (
        <div className="container mx-auto mb-8 px-10">
          <div className="inline-block w-full border-b border-blue-400 py-8">
            <div className="block md:float-left">
              <span className="cursor-pointer text-4xl font-bold text-white">
                <Link href={'/'}>CRBStuffReviews</Link>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className="hidden md:float-left md:contents">
              {categories.map((category) => {
               if(category.isFeatured){
               return(
                <Link key={category.slug} href={`/category/${category.slug}`}>
                  <span className="mt-2 ml-4 cursor-pointer align-middle font-semibold text-white md:float-right">
                    {category.name}
                    {console.log(category.name)}
                  </span>
                </Link>
              )}})}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: You'll get compile errors unless you return something from the array.map.

Comment: Yes, You're right 